# Internal server error 500 on IIS 8

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis, web-config

I'm having really a weird problem with my website. It works fine locally, but online it shows `iis 8 500 - internal server error`.

In the both online and local versions of the site I use the same remote database. The website works online, but it drops when I try to upload a file to the "upload" directory, which is part of the website.

I don't know what the problem is because I can't get any detailed errors. I've added these code pieces in web.config, but still can'tget detailed error descriptions.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
<customErrors mode="Off"/>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
```

I've also set the max file size:

```
<security>
   <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4096" />
   </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

and the size of the file I'm trying to upload is only few KBs. I suspect that the user doesn't have write permissions, and I asked the hosting admins to give write permissions (I'm waiting for that right now).

What do you think its the problem? Also, why am I not getting detailed errors?

Comment: Check that you have the right security permissions for the folder you're uploading to.

Comment: cant access the app pools on the shared hosting (cant find them in iis for the remote server). i guess ill have to talk with their customer support.

Comment: Try modifying the permissions on the folder itself, right click -> security -> users and check that IIS_IUSRS has read/write on it

Comment: thanks, file permissions were the problem. i thought that i had write permissions, but it looks like they were overwritten when the project was published again. is that possible?

Comment: If you replaced the folder with a new one it's possible. Glad it's fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write permissions were the reason why I was getting the error.

I gave the folder read/write permissions before, but it looks like they were overridden when the newer project version was published.

(On publish we delete all files on the destination).